# ModuleNotFoundError: Import issues

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Facing an issue with import with a Django project while following this [tutorial](https://sunscrapers.com/blog/ultimate-tutorial-django-rest-framework-part-1/). I want to import the views from `core/views.py` onto global level to `api/api.py`. Below is my folder structure:

```
api
 |--api
 |    |--init.py
 |    |--api.py
 |    |--settings.py
 |    |--urls.py
 |    |--wsgi.py
 |
 |
 |--core
      |--serializers.py
      |--views.py
      |--models.py
      |--urls.py
      *|...*.py
```

In `views.py`, I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from . import models
from . import serializers
from django.apps import apps
from rest_framework_extensions.mixins import NestedViewSetMixin

class ContactViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ContactSerializer

class RoleViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Role.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RoleSerializer
```

Now, for the import in `api/api.py`, I have:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from api.core import views as core_views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'contact', core_views.ContactViewSet)
router.register(r'role', core_views.RoleViewSet)
```

However, when I run, `python manage.py runserver`, I get the error:

```
      ....
      File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\me\Documents\project\api\api\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .api import router
      File "C:\Users\me\Documents\project\api\api\api.py", line 2, in <module>
        from api.core import views as core_views
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.core'
```

A couple things to note: I am using virtual env, with Django and all relevant tools installed onto it.

This is how my `manage.py` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your tutorial it states that on `api/api.py` the `core` import must be the following:

```
from core import views as core_views
```

I've made some adaptations due to your code.

[image]